# Create Indicator Data Frame Based on Interval Ranges

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I am trying to create a "long" data frame of indicator ("dummy") variables out of a very peculiar type of "wide" data frame in R that has interval ranges of years defining my data.

What I have looks like this:

```
f=data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"),
             year.start=c(1990,1994,1993),year.end=c(1994,1995,1993))

  name year.start year.end
1    A       1990     1994
2    B       1994     1995
3    C       1993     1993
```

**Update: I have changed the value of year.start for A to 1990 from the initial example of 1993 to address some of the answers below which rely on unique values instead of intervals.**

What I would like is a long data frame that would look like this, with an entry for each of the possible years in the original data frame, eg, 1990 *through* 1995 where 1 = present and 0 = absent.

```
 name year indicator
A     1990   1
A     1991   1
A     1992   1
A     1993   1
A     1994   1
A     1995   0
B     1990   0
B     1991   0
B     1992   0
B     1993   0
B     1994   1
B     1995   1
C     1990   0
C     1991   0
C     1992   0
C     1993   1
C     1994   0
C     1995   0
```

Try as I might, I don't see how I can do this with Hadley Wickham's reshape2 package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, similar to the ones above, which aims to be straightforward:

```
zz           <- cbind(name=f[1],year=rep(min(f[-1]):max(f[-1]),each=nrow(f)))
zz$indicator <- as.numeric((f$name==zz$name & 
                            f$year.start<=zz$year & 
                            f$year.end  >=zz$year))
result       <- zz[order(zz$name,zz$year),]
```

The first line builds a template with all the names and all the years. The second line sets `indicator` based on whether it is present in the range. The third line just reorders the result.

Comment: This works on more complicated intervals, such as when I set year.start for A to 1990, correctly creating 18 rows in the results. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If this works for you, plese consider selecting as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Someone else might have suggestion for `reshape2`, but here is a base R solution:

```
years <- factor(unlist(f[-1]), levels=seq(min(f[-1]), max(f[-1]), by=1))
result <- data.frame(table(years, rep(f[[1]], length.out=length(years))))
#    years Var2 Freq
# 1   1990    A    1
# 2   1991    A    0
# 3   1992    A    0
# 4   1993    A    0
# 5   1994    A    1
# 6   1995    A    0
# 7   1990    B    0
# 8   1991    B    0
# 9   1992    B    0
# 10  1993    B    0
# 11  1994    B    1
# 12  1995    B    1
# 13  1990    C    0
# 14  1991    C    0
# 15  1992    C    0
# 16  1993    C    2
# 17  1994    C    0
# 18  1995    C    0
```

Comment: **NOTE**: your solution is not quite correct. `indicator` should be either 1 (present) or 0 (absent), but your `result` for 1993, C is 2. This is because your solution counts the number of occurrences of (A,B,C) in a vector consisting of `year.start` and `year.end` strung together [via `unlist(...)`]. Since for C, 1993 is both beginning and end, it gets counted twice. Using `result$Freq <- ifelse(result$Freq==0,0,1)` will fix it though.

Comment: Thanks, @jlhoward. I was aware of that, and should have mentioned it in my answer. As you point out, though, making any 2's into 1's is pretty trivial. You could also do `result <- transform(result, Freq = as.integer(as.logical(Freq)))`.

Comment: This one-line answer is awesome but doesn't quite work. It does work for the simple example I gave ... but it fails when you change something like year.start for A to 1990. The number of entries in the long data frame should be 18 (eg, 1990 to 1995 for each of the three names), but in fact is only 12 (1990, 1993, 1994, 1995 for each of the three). That is, this solution doesn't take into account the intervals, but rather only the unique values.

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned that requirement in your question? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry! I was trying to create a minimal example but it turned out too be **too** minimal. I also could have been clearer in the question -- which is now fixed. Your answer still doesn't work because 1991 through 1993 should also be 1 for A.

Answer (score 2):

here is a step-by-step breakdown, using data.table

```
library(data.table)
f <- as.data.table(f)

## ALL OF NAME-YEAR COMBINATIONS
ALL <- f[, CJ(name=name, year=seq(min(year.start), max(year.end)))]

## WHICH COMBINATIONS EXIST
PRESENT <- f[, list(year = seq(year.start, year.end)), by=name]

## SETKEYS FOR MERGING
setkey(ALL, name, year)
setkey(PRESENT, name, year)

## INITIALIZE INDICATOR TO ZERO, THEN SET TO 1 FOR THOSE PRESENT
ALL[, indicator := 0]
ALL[PRESENT, indicator := 1]

ALL

   name year indicator
1:    A 1993         1
2:    A 1994         1
3:    A 1995         0
4:    B 1993         0
5:    B 1994         1
6:    B 1995         1
7:    C 1993         1
8:    C 1994         0
9:    C 1995         0
```

Comment: Just like @jlhoward , this works on more complicated intervals, such as when I set year.start for A to 1990, correctly creating 18 rows in the results. Thanks!

Comment: @bshor, that is a consequence of the `CJ` with `seq`

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution

```
f=data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"),
         year.start=c(1993,1994,1993),year.end=c(1994,1995,1993), stringsAsFactors=F)
x <- expand.grid(unique(f$name),min(f1$year):max(f1$year)) 
names(x) <- c("name", "year")
x$indicator <- sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) sum(x$name[i]==f$name & x$year[i] >=    f$year.start & x$year[i] <= f$year.end))
x[order(x$name),]
```

Comment: This answer works for the example given -- thanks! -- but as with the one-line answer from @matthew-plourde, fails when not all the unique values are given in the initial data frame. That is, it doesn't take into account the intervals I'm looking for.